# Whats the difference between Firebase and cloud services (Amazon,Bluehost)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, web-services, backend

I make a swift osx app with a Firebase-server. They can't communicate directly with each other so I made a node js web server (that is running on localhost at the moment). It seems like I need either an own server or the one of a cloud service. Do I still need Firebase and are the cloud services something else or can I replace the Firebase server with the one of the cloud service?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "they can't communicate directly with each other".  What's the problem here?

Comment: There isnt an admin sdk for swift for osx, it only works for ios, so I need a server in between

Comment: There are REST APIs for some services that you can invoke directly from any environment.  Since you haven't said exactly what you're trying to do, it's impossible to say if it's actually *possible* to do what you want without a middleware service.

Comment: I think with @Stas answer my question changed, because as I have commented under his answer I want to save files like .jar and .exe and according to his answer Firebase isnt the best choice to do that. So the new question is: Which is the best cloud service to manage users and save those types of files?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really an appropriate forum for getting product recommendations, else it becomes a destination for advertising and spam.

Comment: Ok, but if you know, can you tell me, if Firebase isnt a good place to store files in Firebase storage, if this doesnt count to product recommendations?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion, which is also not really what Stack Overflow is for.  Stack Overflow is used when you've chosen an implementation and have questions about code that you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firebase** is good place to store plain data like text etc, becomes quite expensive if you start uploading images or any other media data.

**Amazon** is good for everything, but became quite confusing and crowded with their services over the years. The good stuff from there are elastic components for web deployment, load balancing, and cheap data storage, maybe ec2 if u are a bit more advanced and know how to make the required remote OS for your web service.

**Bluehost**, seems like they are targeting wordpress developers mainly and domain registration, i would think of this as the tip of the iceberg when you nearly finished developing and require some decorations on the top. They might have some services like Amazon and Firebase but quite unlikely to beat amazon or firebase prices.

Comment: I also want to save files like .jars, so Firebase isnt a good choice? Which do you think is the best one to handle users and many different files like .jar .exe etc?

Comment: I would think of Amazon S3, just create a bucket and can put anything in there and will be quite cheap, and yes you are right in regards of firebase. It wouldnt be the right choice, its good for web apps just to store auth detaails, maybe some key associated with an account etc, but for files you mentioned my choice would fall for S3 bucket